# DNS: why do we need RR type NS with name and not directly IP?

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver, a-record, ns-record

let's assume I search the NS for the domain yeahman.com. I may get an answer TYPE NS that the server for this domain is  ns55.yeahman.com. Then I need at the same time a TYPE A entry in the additional section to get the IP of ns55.yeahman.com let's say for example here 192.160.155.155
my question is: why do I bother of the name of the server, namely here "ns55.yeahman.com" why I cannot get directly an answer of TYPE  newtype that say's that nameserver for domain yeahman.com is at 192.160.155.155?

Answer (score 2):

I think your question is... Why are NS records DNS names that need to be resolved rather than IP addresses.

The benefit of them being DNS names is that where they point to can change. If a nameserver needs to move IP address, its IP needs to be changed in 1 place and not once for each domain.

Comment: thanks. I would add to complete that if the IP is no longer relevant you can just query the TYPE A for the name server. In other words, TTL for NS should be generally higher than for type A. am I right?